# Move Focus forward when Dialog is dismissed

Tags: android, android-view

I have several `EditTexts` on which I have implemented `onFocusChangedListeners` to open `TimePickers`. How do I change focus to the next `EditText` when the `onTimeSet` is called in the current `TimePicker` (When Time is set in the `TimePicker`)?

Comment: Post the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDateChange, use ;

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```